# is there any way to stream response word by word of chatgpt api directly in react native (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I want to use Chat GPT Turbo api directly in react native (expo) with word by word stream here is working example without stream

```
  fetch(`https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`, {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'hello' }],
    temperature: 0.3,
    max_tokens: 2000,
  }),
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + API_KEY,
  },
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response); //If you want to check the full response
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then((json) => {
      console.log(json); //If you want to check the response as JSON
      console.log(json.choices[0].message.content); //HERE'S THE CHATBOT'S RESPONSE
    });
  }
});
```

what can i change to stream data word by word

Comment: What do you mean by *stream data word by word*?

Comment: @devpolo like in chat gpt website. it streams word by word

Comment: Understood. Have you tried anything yourself? Can you share it to us?

Comment: I try to give stream: true, in the body it does not work also i ask GPT it give answers which can work on web but not in react native

Comment: The snippet is a REST based API call.

Comment: https://github.com/gptlabs/openai-streams Check this?

Comment: You may be better of with this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/. Implement a REST Endpoint that takes your prompts, that keeps your API Key Secret.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar its work in next not in react native

Comment: @AnshumanKumar code in question is REST full api but its not give word by word responce

Comment: Yeah it won't cause that isn't how REST works. You would need a streaming API call.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar can you edit this code?

Comment: I don't know the solution myself, we had also facing the same roadblock in  my current project, so we are using the typewriter effect.

Comment: We've used this React Hook and it seems to work: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/react-chat-stream

Comment: @IbadUrRehman were you able to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

OpenAI APIs rely on SSE ([Server Side Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format)) to stream the response back to you. If you pass the **stream** parameter in your API request, you will receive chunks of data when they are calculated by OpenAI.
This creates the illusion of a real-time response that mimics someone typing.

The hardest part to figure out might be how to connect your frontend with your backend. Every-time the backend receives a new chunk you want to display it in the frontend.

I created a simple NextJs project on [Replit](https://replit.com/@picsoung/OpenAi-Streaming) that demonstrates just that. [Live demo](https://OpenAi-Streaming.picsoung.repl.co)

you will need to install [better-sse package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sse)

`npm install better-sse`

**Server side**
In an API route file

```js
import {createSession} from "better-sse";

const session = await createSession(req, res);
      if (!session.isConnected) throw new Error('Not connected');

const { data } = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: 'text-davinci-003',
  n: 1,
  max_tokens: 2048,
  temperature: 0.3,
  stream: true,
  prompt: `CHANGE TO YOUR OWN PROMPTS`
}, {
  timeout: 1000 * 60 * 2,
  responseType: 'stream'
});

//what to do when receiving data from the API
data.on('data', text => {
  const lines = text.toString().split('\n').filter(line => line.trim() !== '');
  for (const line of lines) {
    const message = line.replace(/^data: /, '');
    if (message === '[DONE]') { //OpenAI sends [DONE] to say it's over
      session.push('DONE', 'error');
      return;
    }
    try {
      const { choices } = JSON.parse(message);
      session.push({text:choices[0].text});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
});

//connection is close
data.on('close', () => { 
  console.log("close")
  res.end();
});

data.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

On your front end you can now call this API route

```js
let [result, setResult] = useState("");

//create the sse connection
const sse = new EventSource(`/api/completion?prompt=${inputPrompt}`);

//listen to incoming messages
sse.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
  let msgObj = JSON.parse(data)
  setResult((r) => r + msgObj.text)
});
```

Hope this makes sense and help others with similar issue.

Comment: I might change that to gpt3-turbo or gpt-4 if  you have the access. But the request format would change for that.

Comment: The model currently set is for GPT3, not ChatGPT.

Comment: sse is not work in react native

Comment: This is a separate  codebase that you can set up on any platform of your choice that will interact with ChatGPT for you and you can  use it to stream responses to your server.

Comment: There are a few workarounds to support SSE in React Native.
Did you try the following libraries?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sse

there is also a discussion on the react-native repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28835
with people that successfully implemented it.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar if you implement it in react native can you share code?

Comment: You cant change model to gtp3 or gpt4 with this rest api. This is incorrect answer

Comment: @rendom you can change it on the server side part on that line `model: 'text-davinci-003`

Comment: How to detect SSE in chrome dev tools? I don't see any entry for response in network tab when the response is being streamed to browser, even though i have selected 'All' in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this GitHub repository: https://github.com/jonrhall/openai-streaming-hooks. I recommend exploring this library as it offers React hooks that function solely on the client-side, requiring no server support.

Comment: Its not working in react native

Comment: I didn't downvote, but would it not be a security risk exposing the API key on the client side? The better approach IMO would be setting up a proxy like @picsoung has, but that wouldcome at the cost of some added latency.

Comment: True, for protecting API key request should be proxied from server. The better application with this library would be to processing info from user's open ai key where it is ok to expose API to client since it belongs to user

Comment: Yes, that depends on the needs of the application. In order to have the user's OpenAI key, you would need to connect with their OpenAI account. If you are trying to build a ChatGPT clone without any login (as some people are nowadays), then I wouldn't reccomend this.

Comment: Connecting OpenAI account only needs API key. True that there are many apps now a days which allows users to use their own API key so that they pay the least depending on their use. I am building a free chrome extension that allows users to use chat gpt in any website interacting with web content. my self using the library for this case so i don't have to set up infra to handle requests with open ai.

Comment: I think this library might be useful to you as well, its a very simple React hook, that does exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/react-chat-stream

Answer (score 0):

React native streaming is now possible with https://github.com/react-native-community/fetch.

This was actually a bug that was never addressed by RN team for a while, and this repo emerged to provide a better fetch that complies with WHATWG Spec

> This is a fork of GitHub's fetch polyfill, the fetch implementation React Native currently provides. This project features an alternative fetch implementation directy built on top of React Native's Networking API instead of XMLHttpRequest for performance gains. At the same time, it aims to fill in some gaps of the WHATWG specification for fetch, namely the support for text streaming.

### Install

```
$ npm install react-native-fetch-api --save
```

### Usage

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', { reactNative: { textStreaming: true } })
  .then(response => response.body)
  .then(stream => ...)
```

You can use the stream object like the normal browser fetch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to add body in the request?

Comment: @SeeratAhmed yes, same way you will send post request normally in fetch

Comment: did you make it's work with stream using chat GPT?

Comment: @CoderGautamYT do I need import fetch from 'rn-fetch-api'? I can not find the library to import

Comment: I got stream = undefined

Comment: Well I think there's many ways to implement it but I used this package: https://github.com/acostalima/react-native-polyfill-globals and imported it on my root file like this: `import { polyfill as polyfillFetch } from 'react-native-polyfill-globals/src/fetch'; polyfill();`. Then fetch can be used acc. to this package as the global polyfills package overrides the default fetch. If you want I can make a video to explain it.