# word to word gpt api responce stream in react native

Tags: react-native, openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

Is there a way to implement GPT API with word to word api

I already try implement in javascript directly into app but its not working

I want to use Chat GPT Turbo api directly in react native (expo) with word by word stream here is working example without stream

Comment: share what you tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826303/is-there-any-way-to-stream-response-word-by-word-of-chatgpt-api-directly-in-reac

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain check code in this link question

Comment: Give this react hook a try: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/react-chat-stream

Comment: Not possible due to stream support in React Native, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27741