# How to achieve text streaming in react native using openai api?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, openai-api, server-sent-events

I am working on a react native chat app, and I would like to use openai api to implement auto replying.
There is stream available from openai's [api](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/streaming), but it uses SSE, which seems not working well in react native.
Is there any way that I can use text streaming in my project?

I have tried most of the advices mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826303/is-there-any-way-to-stream-response-word-by-word-of-chatgpt-api-directly-in-reac) and other solutions, but they were not working as expected.

1. External libraries: I have successfully implemented streaming in React (using Next.js) with libraries like `openai-streams`, `react-chat-stream`, `openai-streaming-hooks` .etc . However, these libraries do not work in react native.
2. Fetch for Streaming: someone mentioned fetch is available for streaming, I tried it, along with libraries like `@async-util/fetch`, `react-native-fetch-api` too. But they weren't working too.
3. React Native WebView: it can make requests and send the response back to the app, inspired by [this](https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-chatgpt) repo, but I think it is not feasible for long term usage as there might be more and more functions coming to the app in the future, I think it will be difficult to maintain as using this method requires injecting js code.
4. SSE Packages: i tried packages such as `react-native-event-source`, `react-native-sse`. However, I'm still encountering issues where the functionality is not working as expected. I'm unsure if the problem lies with my implementation or with the packages.

I am so confused right now. Is there any guidance or working examples to achieve the streaming response?
Here are two proposed solutions that I think is the most appropriate and will keep trying, please tell me if there are any alternative approaches that I should consider or improvements to those methods, I would greatly appreciate the advice.

- implement SSE, but I am relatively new to it, so it would be great if there are some specific boilerplate code or examples provided.
- use a server (like axios?) to receive the stream response and return back to the app, but I am not sure whether the server should be written in the app itself or outside the app. Also, as I am using Expo, I noticed the upcoming ExpoSDK include [api routes](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-router-v3-beta-is-now-available-eab52baf1e3e), does that mean I can write the request in the app later?

Thank you for your time.

---

Respond to zoran404:
Yes, I have tried. The `react-native-polyfill-globals/auto` is added because without it will raise error `Property 'TextEncoder' doesn't exist`. Here are my approach and I am really not sure about it.

```js
import 'react-native-polyfill-globals/auto'
import { fetch } from 'react-native-fetch-api'

async function fetchStreamMessage() {
    const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
    fetch(url, {
      reactNative: { textStreaming: true },
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${OPENAI_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Tell me a joke' }],
        model: 'gpt-4',
        stream: true
      })
    })
      .then((response: Response) => response.body)
      .then((body: ReadableStream) => {
        const reader = body.getReader()
        console.log(reader)
      })
  }
```

Comment: It can work with react-native. Have you tried the code from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77089117/2100372

Comment: The comment is too long so I placed it in the question. Please give me some insights, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the reader from body.getReader(), you need a loop to read the stream chunks. After `const reader = body.getReader()`

```html
            const reader = body.getReader();
            let done, value;
            while (!done) {
                ({ done, value } = await reader.read());
                if (!done) {
                    const chunk = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
                    console.log(chunk);
                }
            }
            console.log('Streaming complete.');
```