# failed React Native stream response for OpenAI completion API from server to client using fetch

Tags: react-native, stream, fetch, streaming, openai-api

From what I understand here:
[Using Readable Streams MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams)

I should be able to use the `Fetch API` to send a result from the server to the client and get the `response.body`, i.e:

`fetch(...).then((response) => response.body);`

In my specific setup, my goal is to use `Node` and `Express` to get a **streamed text response** from the OpenAI API so that I can **handle the text chunk by chunk on the client side !**.

The key issue here is that **React Native does not support**  `ReadableStream` properly and therefore the `response.body` when using `fetch` is `undefined`:

This post is particularly clear and helpful but it does not solve the issue since it isn't using RN:
https://writer.sh/posts/real-time-openai-response-streaming-node-js/

**Example server side:**

```
app.post("/gptText", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const requestBody = {
      model: "gpt-4",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user",
          content: "Say 'hi'",
        },
      ],
      stream: true,
    };

    const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create(requestBody);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");

    for await (const chunk of completion) {
      const [choice] = chunk.choices;
      const { content } = choice.delta;

      if (content !== undefined) {
        console.log(content);
        res.write(content);
      }
    }

    res.end();} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error });
}
});
```

The server code works just fine, producing an output of:

```
Hi
!
How
can
I
assist
you
today
?
```

but when attempting to pase/read the response on the client side, for example:

```
const response = await fetch(...).then((response) => response.body)...
```

the `response.body` is `undefined` instead of being a `ReadableStream` object,
and of course the following desired `const reader = response.body.getReader();` also fails.

Important to note that if I am not using a stream, but rather just sending the entire result as a single sentence, I can get it with `response.text()` for example.

I have tried multiple approaches such as using the `RN-fetch-blob` library or the `react-native-fetch-api` to try and use those suggested `polyfills` for solving streamed responses in **React Native** but they all failed or produced the same results.

I also tried answers on SO such as:
[How to achieve text streaming in react native using openai api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77725698/how-to-achieve-text-streaming-in-react-native-using-openai-api)

which seems to be the closest one to a solution, but this simply did not work, the `body` is still undefined when implementing the post's approach..

Would appreciate to know where I went wrong here or if someone has done a workaround for this specific example.

Thanks :)